# Tab bar malfunction in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-tabs

I was messing around with tab settings in Firefox about 3 years ago and screwed up my tab bar.  I now have a useless blank tab bar with some half-hidden icons.  I've tried to fix it several times.

The problem stays through upgrades and even a reinstall (obviously I didn't uninstall it fully).  This is on a Mac, but I also did the same thing to a PC I no longer have.  I think I was trying to set the tabs to get narrower instead of having to scroll to find all the tabs.  I've searched through the `about:config` screen for values that were "user set" but I can't find anything that affects the tab bar.

Check out the screen shot and notice the tab bar:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you've made a change to the settings in about:config, they will be shown in bold and under the 'Status' column it will show 'user set' However, configuration changes for the UI are usually made in the userchrome.css file, which you can find in the chrome folder in the firefox profile directory.

The first thing you could try is [Safe Mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode_(Firefox)) and see if that helps identify the problem. Personally, I'd create a new [Profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager) It's a simple process, which takes a few minutes and should correct the problem you have.